# Limits of generalized inverse function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

For a nondecreasing function $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ the generalized inverse function is defined as $$F^{-}(y):=\inf\{x\in\mathbb{R}:F(x)\ge y\},$$where $F(-\infty):=\inf\{F(x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}<y<\sup\{F(x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}=:F(\infty)$. Is there anything, that can be said about the limits $\lim\limits_{y\to F(-\infty)}F^{-}(y)$ and $\lim\limits_{y\to F(\infty)}F^{-}(y)$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $F$ is nondecreasing we have that $F(x_n)$ is nonincreasing for any sequence
$x_n$ that nonincreasing. It is also clear that
$$\tag{1}
F(-\infty)=\inf\{F(x):x\in\mathbb R\}=\lim_{n\to\infty} F(x_n)
$$
for a sequence $x_n$ that descends to $-\infty\,.$

By definition of $F^-\,,$
$$\tag{2}
F^-(F(x))\le x\,.
$$
Using the sequence from (1) it follows now that
$$\tag{3}
\lim_{n\to\infty}F^-(F(x_n))\le\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=-\infty\,.
$$
Therefore,
$$\tag{4}
\lim_{y\to F(-\infty)}F^{-}(y)=-\infty\,.
$$

Conversely, it is not true that
$$\tag{5}
\lim_{y\to F(+\infty)}F^{-}(y)=+\infty\,
$$
holds: When $F$ assumes a maximum at $x_*<+\infty$ then $F(+\infty)=F(x_*)$ and
$$\tag{6}
F^-(F(+\infty))=F^-(F(x_*))\le x_*\,.
$$
Therefore, for any sequence $y_n\uparrow F(+\infty)$ we have $F^-(y_n)\le x_*<+\infty\,.$